# How to create a PR request on github when forked repo has't been updated?

Tags: github

I want to create a PR request on the following repository [HERE](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo). Now i had forked the main repo as you can see [HERE](https://github.com/gautamz07/hexo) , as of now its 107 commits behind, there are no code changes in my forked version that i've made , my question how do i go about creating a PR request ?

Do i need to rebase ? do i need to pull from remote on my local system ? How do i go about creating a PR request step by step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a pull request if you don't have anything new in your code.

**Commit and push code on your fork**, then you'll be able to create a pull request.

If you want to catch up with the 107 missing commits, do the following (as explained [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork))

```
git pull https://github.com/hexojs/hexo master
```